# SAS Proc REPORT: How to hide/eliminate repeated values for multiple columns

Tags: sas, report, proc

```
proc report data=DATA nowd headline out=test2
    style(summary)=[color=cx3e3d73 backgroundcolor=cxaeadd9
    Fontfamily=helvetica Fontsize=3 textalign=r];
    column Company_code pid gl Balance Descr Amt Value difference;
    define company_code/group 'Company Code';
    define PID/group;
    define gl/display 'GL Code';
    define balance/analysis sum FORMAT=DOLLAR20. 'Blalance';
    define descr/ display 'Description';
    define amt/analysis max FORMAT=DOLLAR20.2; 
    define value/analysis max FORMAT=DOLLAR20.2 'Market Value';
    define difference/ analysis max FORMAT=DOLLAR20.2 'Difference';
    break after PID/summarize OL skip;
    title 'TEST';
    compute after PID;
    line ' ';
    endcomp;
run;
```

This is the code have, the results report in columns Amt, value and difference have repeaded value.So basically, I only need the value at the header, but I calculated the header by the values abpve it. I don't if there's a way for me to hide them. Like in the image.
[this is the partial results report, I don't need the values above the header, how can I hide them?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkmMb.png)

Comment: Please add some sample data to the question, be sure to include both cases of company_code/PID having one detail row and multiple detail rows.

Answer (score 0):

You are coding Proc REPORT to do a mix of detail and summary.   From [Cynthia Zender post on SAS Community](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/how-to-delete-hide-rows-in-a-report-using-proc-report/td-p/42329)

> The bottom line is that PROC REPORT does not allow you to delete report rows. If report is doing a detail report, with summary lines, you can either have summary lines or not --- but you cannot delete the detail lines and only show the summary lines. To collapse the detail lines, you would move into the world of summary report, but given your data, you are generating a detail report that contains summary lines.

[Cynthia is a SAS author](https://support.sas.com/en/books/authors/cynthia-zender.html) and has taught and presented numerous times on REPORT topics